# Can a Odd Perfect Number be a Carmichael Number?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers, carmichael-numbers

Can a odd perfect number $n$ be a Carmichael number?

We know that all Carmichael numbers are odd and square-free.

But is there a Carmichael number that is also a perfect number?

We all know that if odd perfect numbers exists, it must be form of either $1\pmod{12}$,$81\pmod{324}$, or $117\pmod{468}$.

So if a perfect odd Carmichael number exists, then it must be $1\pmod{12}$, as $81, 117, 324$, and $468$ are all divisible by $9$ and therefore not squarefree.

And a positive integer $n$ is Carmichael number if and only $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401052, but be aware that this proof may not be entirely correct. AFAIK this is the oldest known open problem in mathematics.

Comment: Maybe , I miss something , but does Euler's necessary criterion not already establish that an odd perfect number cannot be squarefree ?

Comment: Should there be no proof , the large lower bound ($10^{1500}$) would make it anyway extremely unlikely that an odd perfect number (if existent at all) can be a Poulet- number let alone a Carmichael number.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303147/proof-that-odd-perfect-numbers-cannot-consist-of-single-unique-factors) for a proof that odd perfect numbers could not be square free.