# Does the following equation have any solutions in $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of **positive integers**.

The function $\sigma(N)$ gives the *sum of the divisors* of $N$.

My question is:

> Does the following equation have any solutions for $x \in \mathbb{N}$?
>   $$\sigma(3x + 1) = 4x + 1$$

Notice that $3x + 1$ must be deficient, and that if we allow $x = 0$, then it is a (trivial) solution.

Furthermore, suppose that $3x + 1 = p^{\alpha}$, where $p$ is prime.  Then we have
$$\sigma(3x + 1) = \frac{p^{\alpha+1} - 1}{p - 1} = \frac{4(p^{\alpha} - 1)}{3} + 1 = 4x + 1,$$
from which we obtain
$$3(p^{\alpha+1} - 1) = 4(p - 1)(p^{\alpha} - 1) + 3(p - 1).$$
Simplifying and collecting like terms, we get
$$0 = p^{\alpha+1} - 4p^{\alpha} + p + 4.$$
Rewriting the last equation, we have
$$(p^{\alpha} + 1)(4 - p) = 8.$$
As $p^{\alpha} + 1 \geq 3$, we have the possibilities
$$(p^{\alpha} + 1, 4 - p) \in \{(4,2),(8,1)\}.$$
Both of them are impossible under the given constraints.

Consequently, $\omega(3x + 1) \geq 2$, where $\omega(y)$ is the **number of distinct prime factors** of $y$.  (That is, $3x + 1$ must be composite.)

Lastly, I tried checking for equality (in the range $0 \leq x \leq 100$) using a spreadsheet, and found only the solution for $x=0$.

I am therefore compelled to predict that:

> The equation $\sigma(3x + 1) = 4x + 1$ *does not* have any solutions for $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Maybe you can utilize a formula form the following link:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to that MSE link, @NoChance!

Comment: Some small results I've got are (1) $2\not\mid 3x+1$ (2) $3\not\mid 3x+1$ (3) $3x+1$ has to be a perfect square.

Comment: I would be more than delighted to hear about your results, @mathlove. =)

Comment: It would be better just to say you have checked over a range instead of listing the whole spreadsheet.  It takes up a lot of space needlessly.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  I have removed the spreadsheet.  Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1** : $2\not\mid 3x+1$.

*Proof* : $x=1$ is not a solution.

For $x\ge 2$, suppose that $2$ is a divisor of $3x+1$. Then, we have
$$4x+1=\sigma(3x+1)\ge 1+(3x+1)+2+\frac{3x+1}{2}$$
There are no $x\ge 2$ satisfying the inequality.$\quad\square$

**Claim 2** : $3x+1$ is a perfect square.

*Proof* : Let $3x+1={p_1}^{a_1}{p_2}^{a_2}\cdots {p_k}^{a_k}$ where $p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_k$ are distinct primes larger than $3$ and $a_i\ge 1\in\mathbb Z$. Then, the equation becomes
$$(1+\cdots +{p_1}^{a_1})(1+\cdots +{p_2}^{a_2})\cdots (1+\cdots +{p_k}^{a_k})=4x+1$$The RHS is odd since $x$ is even. So, $a_i$ has to be even for every $i$.$\quad\square$

Comment: Just a minor comment: Surely $3 \not\mid 3x+1$ as $3x+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$? =)

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : You are right:) Deleting it.