# Sum of reciprocal of the positive divisors of $1800.$

Tags: combinatorics

Sum of reciprocal of the positive divisors of $1800.$

Attempt: divisors of $1800 = 2^3\times 3^2 \times 5^2$

so sum of divisors of $1800$ is $\displaystyle (1+2+2^2+2^3)\times (1+3+3^2)\times (1+5+5^2)$

$ \displaystyle = \bigg(\frac{2^4-1}{2-1}\bigg)\times \bigg(\frac{3^3-1}{3-1}\bigg)\times \bigg(\frac{5^3-1}{5-1}\bigg)$

but answer is different, could some help me to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You need the sum of the reciprocals, you are taking the sum of the divisors themselves.

Comment: yes  астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг but how can i calculate it, thanks

Comment: What about taking the reciprocals: $(1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3})\times(1+3^{-1}+3^{-2})\times(1+5^{-1}+5^{-2})$?

Comment: Oh, just do geometric progression formula on the reciprocals instead. It's the same, basically.

Comment: means divided it by $1800$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sum_{d=1,d|n}^n\dfrac1d=\dfrac1n\sum_{d=1,d|n}^n\dfrac nd=\dfrac1n\sum_{d=1,d|n}^nd$$

Now use [this](http://planetmath.org/formulaforsumofdivisors)

**See also**: [Is there a formula to calculate the sum of all proper divisors of a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number)