# parity of sum of divisors of number n

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the fastest way to calculate parity of sum of divisors of a number without  computing the sum of divisors of the given  number $n$ by the formula stated in these answers [formula to calculate sum of divisors on mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number)

I also came across this code which calculates  the parity of sum of divisors of a number n but couldn't get the logic .

```
// divsum stores the parity of sum of divisors of number n 

    int calc(long long n) {
        bool divisibleBy2 = n % 2 == 0;
        while (n % 2 == 0) n /= 2;
        // n odd
        int nFactors = int (divisibleBy2);
        int divSumParity = 1;
        for (int i = 2; (long long) i * i * i <= n; i ++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                int e = 0;
                while (n % i == 0) n /= i, e ++;
                if (e % 2 == 1) divSumParity = 0;
                nFactors ++;
            }
        }
        if (n > 1) {
            if (isSquare(n)) {
                nFactors += 1;
            } else if (isPrime(n)) {
                nFactors += 1;
                divSumParity = 0;
            } else {
                nFactors += 2;
                divSumParity = 0;
            }
        }
       return 2*(nFactors%2) + divSumParity;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the parity, we need only consider all odd divisors of $n$. That is, if $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd, then we need only check the parity of the sum of divisors of $m$, which just means we need to find out of the *number* of divisors of $m$ is odd or even. And for this, note that divisors come in pairs *except* for a perfect square.
Thus this code would do the job better and faster:

```
int DivisorSumParity(unsigned long long n) {
   assert(n != 0);
   while (n % 2 == 0) n /=2;
   return issquare(n);
}
```

Comment: @the value of n can be as large as 10^15

Comment: can you just look at the code that i have posted ? .i think you can get it easily .

Answer (score 1):

The sum-of-divisors function $\sigma(n)$ is a multiplicative function, because in terms of Dirichlet's convolutions it is simply $\mathbb{1}*\mathbb{1}$. We may notice that if $p$ is an odd prime number
$$ \sigma(p^k) = 1+p+\ldots+p^k $$
has the same parity of $k+1$, and if $p=2$ then $\sigma(p^k)$ is odd. In particular:

> $ \sigma(n) $ is odd if and only if $n$ is a number of the form $2^m(2k+1)^2$.