# Sum of divisors of perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $c,d$ be natural numbers of same parity (both odd or both even) and $\sigma$ be sum of divisors function. Is it known whether or under what conditions $\sigma (c^{2})$=$\sigma (d^{2})$ ? I am guessing that it can happen but unsure if certain things must hold

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22723/572204)?

Comment: Thank you,I don't know if that helps me

Comment: @argamon I'd start with a simpler problem - when $c, d$ are odd primes, it simplifies to solving :$$1+c+c^2 =1+d+d^2$$

Comment: I bet you had tried that, not that interesting..

Comment: Haha, it's just more useful if I know in general but I greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, starting from the simple example $$\sigma (4^2)=\sigma (5^2)$$  we can generate infinitely many by multiplying by a factor prime to $10$. Thus, $$\sigma(12^2)=(1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4)\times (1+3+3^2)=31\times 13=403$$  $$\sigma(15^2)=(1+3+9)\times (1+5+25)=13\times 31=403$$

and so on.

Comment: That's very helpful I wonder if there exist any with the same parity i.e. both odd or both even

Comment: I suggest doing a search.  I also found $\sigma(76^2)=\sigma(95^2)$ but I didn't search very far.  Of course, if two odd numbers satisfied this you could multiply by $4$ to get an example with two even numbers.  Of course both of my examples use the fact that $1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4=1+5+5^2$. And it's easy to make more examples using that. I'd first want to see if there were examples without that.

Comment: In fact, the sum of divisors function is multiplicative, so you can multiply both of them by the square of any number that does not have $2,3,5$ as a factor and get another pair.

Comment: You have $\sigma(4^2)=\sigma(5^2)=31$ and now you can multiply by the square of any number without factors of $2,5$.  The answer is $3^2$ and $76^2,95^2$ is $19^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan  Yes, both my examples are simple consequences of $\sigma(4^2)=\sigma (5^2).  I'll edit to point that out,

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like $\sigma(627^2)=\sigma(749^2)$.

Feel free to check my work. (Or Python's work!)

And here's an even-even pair:
$\sigma(740^2)=\sigma(878^2)$.