# Is there a genral formula to find if a number X has it's factor such that they add upto a muliple of X?

Tags: factoring

I was solving problems while I frequently encountered problems such as "Check if the positive factors of 496 add up to twice of 496", etc. So instead of finding all it's factors which is tiresome, I wanted to know is there a general formula?

Comment: You have a nice answer below for your “twice” case in your question, but your actual question posits any multiple, not just a number’s double.  Do you also want any multiple or just simply twice?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven any multiple

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a formula for $\sigma(n)$, the sum of positive divisors of $n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). According to the formula $\sigma(496)=992=2\cdot 496$, so yes, "it adds up to twice of $496$". A positive integer $n$ is called **perfect** if $\sigma(n)=2n$. For references see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). The first perfect numbers are
$$
n=6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, 
$$

$$
137438691328, 2305843008139952128, 
$$

$$
2658455991569831744654692615953842176, 
$$

$$
191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216 
$$

More generally, $n$ is called *$m$-multiple-perfect*, if $\sigma(n)=m\cdot n$. For example $\sigma(120)=3\cdot 120$. See also [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130607/integers-n-such-that-sigman-omegann-and-omegan-divides-n/130614#130614).

Comment: So did you add all the divisors manually or is there a short cut to find the sum?

Comment: No, there is a recursion formula and several special cases, where I do not need to find the divisors myself. See the link I have given above. For more information see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number).