# Find n with this condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem:

> Let $D = \{ n\in\mathbb{N} | 128000 \vdots n\}$. Calculate $\sum_{n\in D} n$.

We can see that $n = 128000k$, and $n$ needs to be even. But I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. As currently phrased the answer is trivially $\infty$

Comment: What does $128000 \vdots n$ mean?  Do you mean...$n$ is divisible by $128000$?  But then the sum obviously diverges.

Comment: I edited. Im sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $n\,|\,128000$"?

Comment: When using nonstandard notation you should define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the sum of divisors of $128000$ was meant, i.e.,
$$
\sigma(128000)=\sum_{d\mid 128000} d=319332.
$$
Here we can use an explicit formula for $\sigma(n)$, using the prime factorisation $128000=2^{10}\cdot 5^3$ see here:

[Is there a formula to calculate the sum of all proper divisors of a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number)

Comment: Please close (abstract) dupes - don't answer them (with links)

Comment: @Gone I usually do this, but here I was not sure whether it is an exact duplicate. Actually, it was not even clear to me whether or not the question was about $\sigma(n)$. Nevertheless you are right, of course.

Comment: Then you can post a comment. It makes it harder to clean up now that it has an accepted answer, i.e. we need to waste more time doing so...

Comment: OK, next time I will post this as comment.

Comment: Great! $\phantom{.......................................}$