# What are the most efficient ways to calculate the sum of positive divisors function, σ, and aliquot sum, s?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, divisor-sum

---

Given a positive integer $n$, what are the most efficient algorithms for calculating the *sum of positive divisors function* [$\sigma_{1}(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) and the *aliquot sum* [$s(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) ?

---

Comment: There is an explicit [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-number) and also a recursion. And of course $()=\sigma_1(n)-n$ is then clear.

Comment: Finding/using the prime factorization of the number $n$ to compute $s(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$ comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

---

An approach similar to Eratosthenes' Sieve seems efficient, and is based upon the following table …

[image]

---

The following Java program — which is based upon the idea encapsulated in the above table — calculates the aliquot sums $s(1)$ — $s(40)$ …

```
public class GenerateAliquotSums
  {
  public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
    final int MAX_N = 40 ;
    final int NUM_ROWS = MAX_N + 1 ;
    final int NUM_COLS = NUM_ROWS / 2 + 1 ;
    int [] [] divisorTable = new int [NUM_ROWS] [NUM_COLS] ;
    for ( int col = 1 ; col < NUM_COLS ; col ++ )
      for ( int row = (2 * col) ; row < NUM_ROWS ; row += col )
        divisorTable [row] [col] = col ;
    for ( int row = 1 ; row < NUM_ROWS ; row ++ )
      {
      int rowSum = 0 ;
      for ( int col = 1 ; col < NUM_COLS ; col ++ )
        rowSum += divisorTable [row] [col] ;
      System.out.println ( "s(" + row + ") = " + rowSum ) ;
      } // end for
    } // end main method
  } // end GenerateAliquotSums class
```

---

Also follows a similar C++ program calculating aliquot sums $s(1)$ — $s(1000000)$ …

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ;

const int LIMIT = 1000000 ;

int main ( void )
  {
  vector<int> s ( (LIMIT + 1), 1 ) ;
  s[0] = 0 ;
  for ( int col = 2 ; col <= (LIMIT + 1) / 2 ; col++ )
    for ( int row = (2 * col) ; row <= LIMIT ; row += col )
      s[row] += col ;
  cout << "s(" << (s.size() - 1) << ") = " << s[s.size() - 1] << endl ;
  return 0 ;
  } // end function main
```

---

Comment: This is a great way to calculate a table of such values. But my read of the (terse) OP is a way to calculate a single value, for which this would be quite inefficient.